# Bayes' theorem for weather forecast puzzle

Tags: puzzle, bayes-theorem

I found the following example of a case where Bayes' theorem could be used, on [this French wikipedia page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Bayes#Pronostics_contradictoires). No solution has been given though.

---

**Contradictory Forecasts**

- According to weather station $A$, the weather will be nice tomorrow.
- Another station $B$ predicts rainy weather.
- It is known that A makes errors in $25\%$ of all cases, and B in $30\%$ of all cases.
- It is known that on average, $60\%$ of all days are rainy and $40\%$ are nice.

Who is right with what probability?

---

I think I would be able to give one if you see what version of the theorem should be applied, so a small hint would be enough to help me to give an answer.
However, feel free to give a complete answer if you like.

Comment: From this information alone, you don't know enough to solve the problem. Let $N$ be the event that the weather is nice, let $R$ be the event that the weather is rainy, let $AN$ be the event that $A$ says the weather will be nice, and let $BR$ be the event that $B$ says it will rain. We have $P(N \mid AN, BR) = \frac{P(AN, BR \mid N) P(N)}{P(AN, BR \mid N) P(N) + P(AN, BR \mid R) P(R)}$ by Bayes' Theorem. But we are not told $P(AN, BR \mid N)$ or $P(AN, BR \mid R)$. It is possible for $A$ and $B$ to have the given error rates and rarely disagree or for them to disagree frequently.

Comment: We would need to know the probability of both $AN$ and $BR$ when the weather is rainy or nice tomorrow. Maybe they are completely independent given the weather, so e.g. $P(AN, BR \mid R) = P(AN \mid R) P(BR \mid R) = 0.25 \cdot 0.7$, but this is not given in the question.